# how to loop through this array and get the sum?

Tags: php, mysql

I got stuck, my objective was to get the ProductID, hidden inside the $_SESSION['cart'] 
and then use those ID in an sql query to compute the sum

here's my code

```
public function getProductID(){
    $keys = array_keys($_SESSION['cart']);
    return $keys;
}


public function getShippingFee(){
    $ids = $this->getProductID();
    foreach($ids as $id){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deliverycharges WHERE ProductID = $id");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoct($query);
    $sum = $row['Cost'] + $row['Tax'];
    return $sum;   
  }
}
```

the second function that I pasted is wrong, I have done several type of looping and yet, I can't get the real sum..shame on me

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: Before you can create a sum, you need to know of what to create the sum. That's entirely not clear from your question. In general you create a sum by using `+`, so your code looks good.

Comment: It isn't advisable to perform a query inside a loop. You'd better build a single query to retrieve all the results and then parse them with a loop. Apart from that, you'd better escape that `$id` var before passing it to MySQL, just to be sure.

Comment: You are overwriting the $sum variable in the for-each loop. Try this instead:  $sum += $row['Cost'] + $row['Tax'];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you return, the function is exited, so you need to sum everything up at first and then return that after everything is summed up:

```
public function getShippingFee(){
    $ids = $this->getProductID();
    foreach($ids as $id){
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deliverycharges WHERE ProductID = $id");
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
      $sum += $row['Cost'] + $row['Tax'];
    }
    return $sum; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of sum each loop. Use +=

```
public function getShippingFee() {
    $ids = $this->getProductID();
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($ids as $id) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM deliverycharges WHERE ProductID = $id");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoct($query);
        $sum += $row['Cost'] + $row['Tax'];
    }
    return $sum;   
}
```